# obj vector to member function

Tags: c++, function, vector

I can't seem to understand how to pass a vector from a class to a member function. What am I doing wrong here? My errors are:

line column

27     8    [Error] prototype for 'double equip::calcmass(std::vector)' does not match any in class 'equip'

17     10   [Error] candidate is: double equip::calcmass()

60     21   [Error] qualified-id in declaration before '(' token

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class equip
{
    public:
        vector<double> time;
        vector<double> mass;
        vector<double> velocity;
        vector<double> height;
        double calcmass();
        double calcvelocity();
        double calcheight();
        double calctmax(); 
    private:
        double T = 7000;
        double g = 32.2;
        double K = 0.008;
};

double equip::calcmass(vector<double> time)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<time.size(); i++)
    {
        return mass[i] = (3000 - 40 * time[i]) / g;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    equip rocket;
    rocket.time;
    ifstream infile;
    string filename;
    cout<<"Enter input file name for time (t): ";
    cin>>filename;
    infile.open(filename.c_str());

    while(infile.fail())
    {
        cerr<<"Error opening file. \n";
        cout<<"Enter file name: ";
        cin>>filename;
        infile.open(filename.c_str());
    }

    for(i=0; i<rocket.time.size(); i++)
    {
        infile>>rocket.time[i];
    }

    double equip::calcm(rocket.time);

    for(i=0; i<rocket.mass.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<rocket.mass[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Errors: 1) Different declaration of `calcmass` from its definition. 2) `rocket.time;` is not a command. 3) `double equip::calcm(rocket.time);`  calcm is not a member of `equip`

Comment: `double equip::calcmass(rocket.time);` is trying to redefine `calcmass()`. If  you're trying to call the function then use `rocket.calcmass(rocket.time);` You don't need (but can) pass `rocket.time` because `time`is a member of the same class as `calcmass`.

Comment: @Ripi2 Everything works now except 3, I tried `double equip::calcmass(rocket.time);` but it gives me the same error

Comment: @DanielNguyen You call member functions on _objects_ of a class, so you want `rocket.calcmass(rocket.time)`.  I'm not sure why you're passing a member of `rocket` to a `rocket` member function though.  A member function already has access to all of the members of the class you called it on.

Comment: @Ripi2 When I compile and run now there are no errors, but nothing happens after I enter the input file. The input file is setup right with the correct name and content. Appreciate the suggestions

Comment: @DanielNguyen Your program has a couple of remaining problems.  `rocket.time` is initially empty, so your first `for` loop in `main` will never be entered.  Once you fix that your program's behavior will still be undefined because `rocket.mass` will be empty when you attempt to write to its elements in `calcmass`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Sorry I still don't understand, should I use `while` and `.push_back()` loop instead?

Comment: @DanielNguyen Yes, you need to either `push_back` elements into your `vector`s or `resize` them before writing to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your class you define `double calcmass();` which takes NO arguments and returns a double but later you try to declare it as `double equip::calcmass(vector<double> time)` which takes a vector of doubles and returns a double. You should change the declaration within the class to `double calcmass(vector<double> time);`

In C++ it is possible to overload functions, meaning two functions can have the same name but take different arguments. This means that you are referring to two different functions in your code.